# Flatten an array and keep index as its value of position

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash

`$scope.data = [[1,2,3], [1,5,6,7], [2,3]];`

I would use 
`_.flatten($scope.data)`so scope.data would be something like

`$scope.data = [1,2,3,1,5,6,7,2,3];`

But I would like to keep the index of the array in each element that was flattened

so I would have something like:

```
$scope.data = [{value:1, index:1},
                  {value:2, index:1},
                  {value:3, index:1},
                  {value:1, index:2},
                  {value:5, index:2},
                  {value:6, index:2},
                  {value:7, index:2},
                  {value:2, index:3}
                  {value:3, index:3}];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through the original array like so:

```
function flatten(arr)
{
    var returnArray = new Array();
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        for(var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++)
        {
            returnArray.push({"value" : arr[i][j], "index" : i});
        }
    }
    return returnArray;
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: this does what I want, so thanks for your reply :) but it would add more complexity to what I have, there is no other way to do so? Like in one line? If i am missing some nice library that could do this

Comment: @unpix the one line is this: `var array = flatten(oldArray);` ;) Just store the function in a javascript file and call it in one line. You can hide the "complex" code in a javascript file that your page links to.

Comment: I gave it +1, so there is none function in some library that could do the same as this piece of code right?

Comment: @unpix I'm not sure you would have to do a `google` search...I am skeptical that you would find anything this seems like a fairly specific case.

Comment: already did it before posting this question here :P Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var input = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 5, 6, 7], [2, 3]],
    output;

output = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], input.map(function(arr, idx) {
        return arr.map(function(el) {
            return { "value": el, "index": (idx + 1) };
        });
    })
);

console.log(JSON.stringify(output));
// [{"value":1,"index":1},{"value":2,"index":1},{"value":3,"index":1},{"value":1,"index":2},{"value":5,"index":2},{"value":6,"index":2},{"value":7,"index":2},{"value":2,"index":3},{"value":3,"index":3}]
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7vc1hbfs/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in pure **functional way** :

```
  var data = [[1,2,3], [1,5,6,7], [2,3]];

  function flat(arr){
    return arr.reduce(function(result, current, index){
      return result.concat(current.map(function(elm){
        return {value: elm, index: index + 1}
      }))
    }, []);
  }

console.log(flat(data));
```

Comment: You need index + 1. Cheers!

Comment: I usually start from 0, but it's not really hard to change it ^^